# How to check which customers are holding both products in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows, with many customers and only 2 products (A and B). It is possible for a customer to hold multiple instances of the same product (e.g customer 1 has 4 product A's in the below table). How can I get a list of all customer who hold both products A and B (regardless of quantity)? Thanks.

e.g. the below table should only return customer ID of 1 and 2 since customer 3 only holds product B.

| Customer ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 1 | A |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need datframe back

```
df[df.groupby('Customer ID')['Product'].transform(lambda x: x.count()>1)]

     Customer ID Product
0            1       A
1            1       B
2            1       A
3            2       A
4            2       A
5            1       A
6            2       B
7            1       A
9            1       A
```

If you need boolean return

```
df.groupby('Customer ID')['Product'].apply(lambda x: x.count()>1).to_frame('BothProducts')


               BothProducts
Customer ID              
1                    True
2                    True
3                   False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` + `nunique`

```
s = df.groupby('Customer ID')['Product'].nunique()
s.index[s==2]
Out[41]: Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='Customer ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the table to a format that is easier to filter using `crosstab`. I've included additional code as example how to filter out only the customers that hold both products:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer ID': [1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,3,1], 
                   'Product': ['A','B','A','A','A','A','B','A','B','A']})

# Transform Product A and B in seperate columns
# New DF indicates the sum of each product the customer owns
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Customer ID'], df['Product'])

# Create boolean column that shows if a customer has both products
df2['Both'] = np.where((df2['A'] > 0) & (df2['B'] > 0), True, False)

#  Optionally: Show only customers with both products
df3 = df2[df2['Both'] == True]
print(df3)

# Optionally: Create list of customers holding both products
print("Customers holding both products:")
print(df3.index.tolist())
```

Console output

```
Product      A  B  Both
Customer ID            
1            5  1  True
2            2  1  True

Customers holding both products:
[1, 2]
```